# Commands inside a Cog not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a dsicord bot, after I got most of the commands working I wanted to clean the project with code I tried this but it raises a commandNotFoundError

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class music(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot


#join a voice channel
@commands.command(name ='join')
async def join(self, ctx):

   channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
   await channel.connect()


@join.error
async def join_error(self, ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error,
              commands.CommandInvokeError) and not is_connected(ctx):
       await ctx.send("You must be in a Voice Channel for the Bot to Join")
   elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
       await ctx.send("Oden Already in the voice channel")




 def is_connected(ctx):
   voice_client = discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
   return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()


def setup(bot):
   bot.add_cog(music(bot))
```

and in the main class I implemented this

```
cogs = ["cogs.music"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  for cog in cogs:
    bot.load_extension(cog)
```

and I don't know if this is relevant but since it's my first time using it I will add it as well, I'm coding it on Replit and the   [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seWuF.png) is like so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it was through Replit do you want me to have a look through the site see if I can see anything...?
Also in your main file this is a better way of doing the cogs then you don't have to add them all manually

```
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
  if filename.endswith('.py'):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```